# MYSQL - Append multiple select queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MYSQL Adminer 4.8.0 4.8.1

I am trying to form a single query from below select queries,
is their any way ir can be done?

There are 4-5 queries so i am afraid

```sql
$productId = 9244
$currentSite = 3
$image_path = 'any';

SELECT `value` from `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` = 'dollskill_catalog/product/base_media_url';

SELECT `label`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
WHERE `value_id` = (SELECT `value_id`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` 
WHERE `value` LIKE '".$image_path."')
LIMIT 1;

SELECT `child_id`
FROM `catalog_product_relation`
WHERE `parent_id` = '".$productId."'
LIMIT 1;

SELECT `rule_price`
FROM `catalogrule_product_price`
WHERE  `product_id` = '".$productId."'
LIMIT 1;

SELECT value
FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
WHERE `row_id` = '".$productId."'  AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price'))

SELECT `value`
FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `scope` = 'websites' AND `path` = 'currency/options/default' AND `scope_id` = '".$currentSite."';

SELECT e.sku,value from catalog_product_entity e
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id = v.row_id and e.entity_id = '".$productId."' and
attribute_id IN (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code IN ('name','sku'));
```

It would be very very helpful, if i get single query for this. Not sure if its easy to do it. but i am quite new in mysql so not getting exaclty.

I have tried using `UNION` but that won't work.

I have tried

```
SELECT parent.entity_id AS parent_id, 
       simple.entity_id AS simple_id, 
       parent.sku AS sku, simple.sku AS simple_sku 
       ccd.value AS base_media_url 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent 
JOIN catalog_product_super_link AS link ON parent.row_id = link.parent_id 
JOIN catalog_product_entity AS simple ON link.product_id = simple.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN core_config_data AS ccd ON path = 'dollskill_catalog/product/base_media_url' 
WHERE parent.entity_id IN (9244) LIMIT 1
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried using "UNION"

Comment: Yes but that won't work.

Comment: When something is "not working" you need to ***EDIT*** your question and clarify if there was a MySQL error and if so what it was, or if there was a result you didn't expect.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

These queries you want to unify are mostly unrelated to each other by table, result data type, or WHERE criteria.  So, it may not make sense to put them into a single query.

A pattern you could try to use is this, where you use `UNION ALL` to generate a resultset with item names and values.

```sql
SELECT 'value' name, `value` number, NULL value
 from `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` = 'dollskill_catalog/product/base_media_url';
UNION ALL
SELECT 'label' name, NULL number, `label` value 
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
    WHERE `value_id` IN (SELECT `value_id`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` 
       WHERE `value` LIKE '".$image_path."')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'child_id' name, `child_id` number, NULL value 
FROM `catalog_product_relation`
WHERE `parent_id` = '".$productId."'
```

This gives you a resultset like this, with one row for each of your SELECTS.

```
name         number     value
value        1234       NULL
label        NULL       the label
child_id     98765      NULL
```

But this is a much bigger pain in the xxx neck to code and to read than simply issuing multiple queries. I think you should go ahead with the multiple queries. The one who maintains your code will thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tried this but it has errors.

Comment: I didn't say it was complete and tested code. It's intended to show a particular pattern. A word to the wise: don't just copy and paste code from Stack Overflow, or anywhere on the intertoobz, without making sure you understand it.